# Code First Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Is the following good design for doing entity framework code first? What am I missing for a production system? I haven't included all my code, just a snapshot...

My application, doesn't update the database; it just reads it.

```
public class Document
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Int32 DocumentID { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Boolean? Status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Document Text"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String DocumentText { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false), DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public String DocumentFolderPath { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false), DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public String DocumentJSONPath { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentID")]
    public virtual DocumentMetadata Metadata { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Int32 PageID { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Page"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public Int32 PageNumber { get; set; }

    [Required, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Int32 DocumentID { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false), DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public String ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Page Text"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public String PageText { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public String HighlightedText { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PageID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Word> Words { get; set; }
}

public class ArchiveDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ArchiveContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(ArchiveContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            GetDocuments().ForEach(d => context.Documents.Add(d));
            GetDocumentMetatdata().ForEach(d => context.DocMetadata.Add(d));
            GetPages().ForEach(d => context.Pages.Add(d));
            GetWords().ForEach(d => context.Words.Add(d));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private static List<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        var documents = new List<Document> {
            new Document
            {
                DocumentID = 1,
                DocumentFolderPath = @"Doc1",
                DocumentJSONPath = @"Doc1.json",
                Status = true
            },
            new Document
            {
                DocumentID = 2,
                DocumentFolderPath = @"Doc2",
                DocumentJSONPath = @"Doc2.json",
                Status = true
            }
        };
        return documents;
    }

public class ArchiveContext : DbContext
{
    public ArchiveContext()
        : base("archiveDB")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DocumentMetadata> DocMetadata { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Word> Words { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you're missing anything for a production system?

Comment: This is the first time I've used EF so I don't know what I don't know. ;)

Comment: You got it working?

Comment: I don't think the `ICollection<Page>` navigation property can have a FK attribute AND work. But I could be wrong. It just... looks weird to me. I've favorited this question, I'll get back to it when I have a chance :)

Comment: Yes it is working. It looks like it gets the data as expected. I just want to know if this is the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you chose the code-first approach, I presume you don't have to deal with the constraints of an existing database. If that assumption is correct, then I'd say you've done it the hard way.

**Convention Over Configuration**

Entity Framework can infer keys (primary and foreign) from the names of your entity members; your code isn't leveraging this formidable capability.

For a *greenfield project*, I like to start with a base entity type:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // inferred PK
    public DateTime DateInserted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can derive, say, `Document` from that class:

```
public class Document : EntityBase
{
    public bool? Status { get; set; }
    public string DocumentText { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual DocumentMetadata Metadata { get; set; } // inferred FK
}
```

The PK is inferred from the inherited `Id` property (or `[TypeName]Id`), and the mere mention of a `virtual` property referencing another entity type is enough for EF to understand you want a FK there.

I'll pause here to mention that I was somewhat thrown off by your non-usage of the C# language aliases for `System.String`, `System.Int32` and `System.Boolean`. They're typically written as `string`, `int` and `bool`.

---

You mention you're only *reading* from the database. This sounds like you're going *code-first* with an *existing* database. It's certainly possible, but the best way to do this in my opinion, is to *[reverse-engineer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx)* the database into entity classes - then you get the best of both worlds, and the generated code can teach you a lot about how EF works.

---

I think the presence of `DisplayAttribute` and `NotMappedAttribute` smells like you're possibly using your entities as both *data entities* and *presentation / ViewModels*. I think I would separate these concerns and create separate classes for presentation purposes,  where `HighlightedText` means something relevant.

Also note that relying on a declarative `DisplayAttribute` will make it quite a pain to localize the application, if you ever need to do that in the future; you'll want these things resolved at run-time, accounting for `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`.

---

The naming is overall ok, except I don't like the `Status` column. It's just too vague of a name. What do the `null`, `true` and `false` values mean? The name should convey that meaning. Also I wouldn't prefix most of `Document`'s members with the word "Document", and `ID` should follow the PascalCasing convention and be `Id`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I will be updating my code with your suggestions. About the FK being explicitly set, when I didn't have it there, the database did not create a foreign key in the database. It may be because it wasn't recognizing my id's as keys. I will try it and find out.